# can't pull without push commit

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

-

I working on project in bitbucket and  I tried to pull my partner commit put I got this

[image]

Comment: "Please commit your changes or stash them before you can merge." Whats unclear?

Comment: @tkausl I just open the project I didn't make any changes to commit it now I need to pull it

Comment: @tkausl and before that I got same problem like that and I pushed a commit then pull other commits, but the project crash

Answer (score 1):

You (or the editor) have made local change, so you cannot simply pull.

1. If you want to discard any local change, then before pull, reset all files by typing

git reset --hard

2. If you want to save these changes, then commit it, pull, and then resolve conflicts if there is any.
3. If you are not sure or not familiar with git, backup the two files indicated to somewhere else, and use 1. to reset them.

In my opinion, if you do not remember any change you made, simply use 1.

Comment: I just want to pull the changes because I didn't make any changes in my local, how I can do it with SourceTree

Comment: There is another option, you can stash the changes using `git stash save`, pull the latest commit and reapply them the working directory using `git stash apply` if you would like to merge them to the latest commit instead

Comment: @Astr-o actually I'm not familiar with git, I just use SourceTree, do u know how I can do it with it?

Comment: @joda when you open up the branch tab is SourceTree, should see a list of files labeled "unstaged", select them all, right click and select discard. Just be careful if you actually want to keep these changes they will be gone. 

Have you changed the files on purpose?

Comment: Also just as an aside, I tend to find the git commandline alot easier to use then alot of the GUI based tools, so I would recommend taking some time to learn it (even though it can be painful if you arent into that